# Why are Run test gutter icons disappearing in IntelliJ IDEA when using a custom Mocha interface with additional parameter?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, mocha.js

I would need your help regarding one issue which we are facing when using IntelliJ IDEA for the developing of our automation tests.

We needed to create our own Mocha custom interface (https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Third-party-UIs) where we basically just adding a new parameter to BDD interface for 'it' and for 'describe', see below

- `describe( "Suite title",  async () => { ... });` -> `describe( "Suite title",  async () => { ... },  "Additional parameter");`
- `it( "Test title",  async () => { ... });` -> `it( "Test title",  async () => { ... },  "Additional parameter");`

In the test file, if we use this additional parameter for the suite, Run test gutter icons disappear (include for tests) and we are unable to find any solution how to fix.
Note: It is curious that when we remove this additional parameter from the suite but keeping it for tests, then Run test gutter icons are displayed.

[image: Missing run test gutter icons]

Do you have any idea what could be wrong? Are we missing something in the implementation? Or do we need some extra configuration in IDEA?

I attached the screenshot where you can see how IDEA behaves in these two situations.

Below, you can see our simplified implementation of our Mocha custom interface which can be used for reproducing of the issue.

CustomInterface.ts:

```
import { Func, AsyncFunc, Suite, Test } from "mocha";
import * as Common from "mocha/lib/interfaces/common";
import * as Mocha from "mocha";

declare module "mocha" {
  namespace interfaces {
    function myCustomInterface(suite: Mocha.Suite): void;
  }

  export interface SuiteFunction {
    (title: string, fn: (this: Suite) => void, myNewParam?: string): Suite;
  }

  export interface TestFunction {
    (title: string, fn?: AsyncFunc, myNewParam?: string): Test;
  }
}

module.exports = Mocha.interfaces.myCustomInterface = function (suite) {
  const suites = [suite];

  suite.on("pre-require", function (context, file, mocha) {
    const common = Common(suites, context, mocha);

    context.before = common.before;
    context.after = common.after;
    context.beforeEach = common.beforeEach;
    context.afterEach = common.afterEach;

    context.run = mocha.options.delay && common.runWithSuite(suite);

    (context.describe as any) = function (
      title: string,
      fn: (this: Suite) => void,
      myNewParam: string
    ) {
      console.log("Suite new param: ", myNewParam);
      return common.suite.create({
        title,
        file,
        fn,
      });
    };

    (context.it as any) = function (
      title: string,
      fn: Func | AsyncFunc,
      myNewParam: string
    ) {
      console.log("Test new param: ", myNewParam);
      const suite = suites[0];
      if (suite.isPending()) {
        fn = null;
      }

      const test = new Test(title, fn);

      test.file = file;
      suite.addTest(test);
      return test;
    };
  });
};
```

myTest.spec.ts

```
// Run test gutter icons are correctly displayed in IDEA
describe("Suite without annotation", () => {
  // Run test gutter icon IS displayed
  it(
    "Test with annotation",
    async () => {
      // Run test gutter icon IS displayed
      console.log("");
    },
    "This is *test* new param"
  );
});

// Run test gutter icons are NOT displayed in IDEA
describe(
  "Suite with annotation",
  () => {
    // Run test gutter icon IS NOT displayed
    it(
      "Test with annotation",
      async () => {
        // Run test gutter icon IS NOT displayed
        console.log("");
      },
      "This is *test* new param"
    );
  },
    "This is *suite* new param"
);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tests",
  "description": "ui tests",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.6.4",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.0.3",
    "typescript": "4.5.4",
    "mocha": "^10.1.0",
    "mocha-multi-reporters": "^1.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "author": "Oracle/NetSuite",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npx mocha --require ts-node/register --require tsconfig-paths/register -u ./CustomInterface.ts ./tests/*.spec.ts"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2018",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the IDE is statically analyzing the source code looking for known code patterns when detecting the tests/suits. As you have customized the interface by adding more parameters to standard functions, they are not recognized as test suits/tests. There are no workarounds unfortunately.

We have a feature request for providing support for custom test/suite names, [WEB-37848](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37848), please feel free to vote for it.
The problem with Mocha custom interfaces is logged as [WEB-61278](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-61278/No-run-test-gutter-icons-when-adding-a-new-parameter-to-the-Mocha-custom-interface-suite)